# Qt Bluetooth stack performance

Tags: android, performance, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an Android app that involves bluetooth low energy communication. I use the Qt Bluetooth stack to do so.

I have experienced that the device discovery is quite slow, compared to other apps that are written in native language. Is there any way I can tweak the device discovery performance? I use the QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent class to discover devices.

Thanks in advance,
JRoorda

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Qt 5.8 by tuning up the BLE discovery:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46253